# 301 redirection in .htaccess vs PHP http_redirect()

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Is there any difference, with respect to SEO, performance, or otherwise, in setting 301 redirects in a .htaccess file vs calling PHPs http_redirect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the .htacess method prevents PHP being invoked which is technically faster. As it's sometimes said that SEO is influenced by response time, this can be a benefit.

Next to that webservers most often have a better implementation of the redirect procedure which is often honoured by SEO - and if not that, then by your potential site users.

If you're looking for a better implementation in PHP, see [`http_redirect`](http://php.net/http_redirect).

Comment: @hakre- thanks, I actually didn't even know about http_redirect(), and changed my answer accordingly. Can you expand on your second paragraph though, I don't quite understand what you mean there.

Comment: If you do a redirect via HTTP headers, you can send only headers or provide more. It's better to provide more, e.g. a descriptive HTTP body (that's what you know as webpage, the HTML) that tells the user that there is a redirect. That's what should be done according to the HTTP standard since ages, many users forget that part (either because they don't know or because it's "more work"). I've seen positive effects in both usability and how robots react to it. `http_redirect` is a good start and the manual tells what it does in detail which is informative as well.

Comment: If you make the server to perform the redirect, this is normally already taken care of, so you automatically benefit with the .htaccess from the better implementation and you don't need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is no difference. The response from the server would be the same.

Also, I'd say that there's no difference in performance, or that it's not really measureable.

In either case, the server has to open a file (either .htaccess or .php) and would then redirect. I'm unsure, if loading the php processor would make a noticeable difference. Maybe if the site is hammered by thousands of requests per second. ;)